# How can I pass an arbitrary group of parameters “through” a method?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I am using AIR v32.0. I have a class which extends netConnection. I need to override an existing method which receives an arbitrary group of parameters. I need to do a few odds & ends then let the original code handle the rest. I understand how to receive the parameters “…parameters” but I can’t find the proper way of calling the original code when I am done.

What I have so far which does not work is;

```
public override function call(strCommand:String, rspResponder:Responder,...parameters):void
{
    trace("parameters.length=" + parameters.length)
    if (parameters.length == 0)
    {
        super.call(strCommand, rspResponder);
    }
    else
    {
        super.call(strCommand, rspResponder, parameters);
    }
}
```

The line;

super.call(strCommand, rspResponder);

Works as expected.

The line;

super.call(strCommand, rspResponder, parameters);

does not appear to be handled by the “call” method properly.

How can I properly pass the “…parameters” on to the “super.call” method of the netConnection class?

EDIT:

There is no error per se. What happens is it sends a message off to the FluorineFX web service in a format the web service is not expecting which then Ralphs on its shoes. The error is "Processing level error description Could not find a suitable method with name LoginCheck" If I remove the overidden method everything works fine.

When I look at the output results in Fiddler, there is a difference in some of the non printable characters between running it with & without the overridden method. But I cannot determine what the practical difference is.

Additional EDIT:

I have a very poor partial work around (at least it works), and perhaps this will spark someone's imagination. I would be embarrassed to put this into production.

```
public override function call(strCommand:String, rspResponder:Responder,...parameters):void
{
    trace("parameters.length=" + parameters.length)
    switch (parameters.length)
    {
        case 0:
            super.call(strCommand, rspResponder);
            break;
        case 1:
            super.call(strCommand, rspResponder, parameters[0]);
            break;
        case 2:
            super.call(strCommand, rspResponder, parameters[0], parameters[1]);
            break;
        case 3:
            super.call(strCommand, rspResponder, parameters[0], parameters[1], parameters[2]);
            break;
        case 4:
            super.call(strCommand, rspResponder, parameters[0], parameters[1], parameters[2], parameters[3]);
            break;
        case 5:
            super.call(strCommand, rspResponder, parameters[0], parameters[1], parameters[2], parameters[3], parameters[4]);
            break;
        case 6:
            super.call(strCommand, rspResponder, parameters[0], parameters[1], parameters[2], parameters[3], parameters[4], 
                                                 parameters[5]);
            break;
        case 7:
            super.call(strCommand, rspResponder, parameters[0], parameters[1], parameters[2], parameters[3], parameters[4],
                                                 parameters[5], parameters[6]);
            break;
        case 8:
            super.call(strCommand, rspResponder, parameters[0], parameters[1], parameters[2], parameters[3], parameters[4], 
                                                 parameters[5], parameters[6], parameters[7]);
            break;
        case 9:
            super.call(strCommand, rspResponder, parameters[0], parameters[1], parameters[2], parameters[3], parameters[4], 
                                                 parameters[5], parameters[6], parameters[7], parameters[8]);
            break;
        case 10:
            super.call(strCommand, rspResponder, parameters[0], parameters[1], parameters[2], parameters[3], parameters[4], 
                                                 parameters[5], parameters[6], parameters[7], parameters[8], parameters[9]);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the error?

Comment: There is no error per se. What happens is it sends a message off to the FluorineFX web service in a format the web service is not expecting which then Ralphs on its shoes. The error is "Processing level error description Could not find a suitable method with name LoginCheck" If I remove the overidden method everything works fine.

Comment: I added additional information to the question.

Answer (score 5):

To pass the extra **...arguments**, which come in a form of **Array**, you need to invoke the method in a special [Function.apply(...)](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Function.html#apply()) way. The thing is, a **Function** in **AS3** (or maybe in **ECMA** standards in general) is an **Object** too thus it has some own properties and methods, which, in certain cases, allow to perform some weird looking tricks.

```
public override function call(strCommand:String, rspResponder:Responder, ...parameters:Array):void
{
    trace("parameters.length=" + parameters.length);
    
    // Create a single deflated Array of incoming arguments.
    var args:Array = [strCommand, rspResponder].concat(parameters);
    
    // A special way of invoking a function where you provide
    // all its arguments in a form of a single Array.
    super.call.apply(this, args);
}
```

Keep in mind, I didn't test that. Also, I never tried **apply(...)** on overrides, but in theory there should be no problems, I think?

Comment: Eureka, success. Worked great, thank you.